# Multiple shopping cart on single domain

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

I'm wondering is it possible to have multiple Paypal shopping cart in one domain/site?

Edited:

One website, has many businesses which also have many products.
Each business has it's own paypal account and hence cart.

Is it possible to hold 1+ such shopping carts on one website, and how can the session to be managed to store the items in the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short, yes.** You can have multiple shopping carts, one for each business, or a shopping cart that handles multiple vendors. How you may implement it such a cart depends on your specific needs.

Here are some helpful links:

[PayPal Adaptive Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro)

> Adaptive payments handles payments between a sender of a payment and
>   one or more receivers of the payment. Senders and receivers can have
>   any PayPal account type. Senders and receivers are not required to
>   have PayPal accounts initially.

[iScripts MultiCart](http://www.iscripts.com/multicart/) (Result of quick Google search)

> Open source shopping cart script that handles multiple vendors thereby
>   generating multiple store fronts.Each seller has their own
>   administrative area to manage their own products, orders, and
>   shipments. Buyers will be able to buy from one seller or multiple
>   sellers at a time.